# Can a PersistentVolumeClaim bind to multiple PersistentVolumes?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-storage, persistent-volumes

I have a GCE Container Cluster composed of 3 nodes. On every node I run a POD like that one:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: none
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello
          image: gcr.io/persistent-volumes-test/alpine:v1.2
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 0.2
              memory: "10Mi"
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/persistentDisk"
            name: persistent-disk
          ports:
          - containerPort: 65535
            name: anti-affinity
            hostPort: 65535
      volumes:
        - name: persistent-disk
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: myclaim
```

The trick of defining the "anti-affinity" port ensures that every POD runs on a different node. I've created 3 PersistentVolume defined like this:

```
 kind: PersistentVolume
 apiVersion: v1
 metadata:
    name: persistent-volume-1
    annotations:
      volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "slow"
    labels:
      release: "dev"
 spec:
    capacity:
      storage: 10Gi
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
    gcePersistentDisk:
      pdName: persistent-disk-1
      fsType: ext4
```

and they are well deployed

```
NAME                  CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STATUS      CLAIM             REASON    AGE
persistent-volume-1   10Gi       RWO           Released    default/myclaim             13h
persistent-volume-2   10Gi       RWO           Released    default/myclaim             5h
persistent-volume-3   10Gi       RWO           Available                               5h
```

the claim definition is the following:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myclaim
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "slow"
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      release: "dev"
```

What I noticed is that the claim bounds only to one of the volumes I created, so, only one of my PODS can get successfully deployed. What I expected was that the claim, when used by a POD, would have found one available volume to bound to, matching selectors rules.
In other words, what I've interpreted of PersistentVolumeClaims is that a POD use claim to search an available volume in a set o PersistentVolumes matching PVC specs. So that's my question:

can the same PersistentVolumeClaim be used by differente instances of the same POD to be connected to different PersistentVolumes? Or the claim is bound to one and only one volume once it is created and cannot bound to any other volume?

If the right answer is the second, how can I make a POD to be dynamically bound to a PersistentVolume (chosen form a set) when deployed whitout creating a claim per POD and thus avoiding to create a specific POD for every volume I need to connect to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `PersistentVolumeClaim` reserves a specific instance of storage that satisfies its request. Using that same `PersistentVolumeClaim` in multiple `Pods` will attempt to use the same bound `PersistentVolume` in each of the `Pods`, which will not be possible in the case of a `gcePersistentDisk`.

Try creating a separate `PersistentVolumClaim` for each `Pod`.

The [Lifecycle](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/#lifecycle-of-a-volume-and-claim) section of the [Persistent Volumes doc](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes) provides a nice overview.

Comment: Thus I have to create 3 different `Pods`, each one using a different  `PersistentVolumeClaim`, I can't use the `Deployment` above that replicates  3 times the same `Pod`, that's right?

Comment: With a Deployment, that is correct. I believe the [PetSet](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/) object provides the type of storage abstraction you're looking for (but PetSets are pretty new, and I'm not as familiar).

Comment: I think `Pets` are what I need: `PetSets` are also referred as [“clustered applications”](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/#what-is-a-pet-set) that's exactly what I'm trying to build. I'll investigate how to use them.